# Authentication returns None in django rest frame work API

Tags: django, api, rest, django-rest-framework, django-views

## views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def login(request):
    data = {}
    email = request.data.get('email')
    password = request.data.get('password')
    user = authenticate(email = email, password = password)
    U = User.objects.get(email=email)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        data['response'] = 'successfully logged in'
    elif Userprofile.objects.filter(email=email).exists() == False:
        data['response'] = 'user does not exist'
    elif U.is_active == False:
        data['response'] = 'Please verify your email'
    else:
        data['response'] = 'invalid password'
    return JsonResponse(data)
otp=random.randint(11111,99999)
@api_view(['POST'])
def signup(request):
    serializer = UserprofileSerializer(data=request.data)
    data = {}
    if serializer.is_valid():
        name = serializer.validated_data['name']
        email = serializer.validated_data['email']
        phone_number = serializer.validated_data['phone_number']
        password = make_password(serializer.validated_data.get('password'))
        account = Userprofile.objects.create_user(name = name, email = email, phone_number = phone_number, password = password)
        data['response'] = 'successfully registered a new user'
        send_mail(
            'Welcome to Trycompound',
            'Your OTP is '+str(otp),
            EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            [email],
        )
        user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        user.otp = otp
        user.save()
    else:
        data = serializer.errors
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

I really can'f figure what's wrong because I have actually done these with the normal templates and when i tried it with the django rest framework, I am unable to login because authenticate is returning 'None'.
and yes User is active, it says 1 in the database.

Answer (score 1):

authenticate function will return none if credentials are invalid. It will return the user object if the credentials are valid. [Click here for more info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users) and it takes username and password as parameters

Comment: Yeah, the credentials are correct, I don't know if it's because I am using a BaseUsermanager

Comment: if you use CustomUserModel then you can write your own authentication function i.e
<code>
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
def authenticate(**cred):
     assert cred.get("password"), "Password is required"
     assert cred.get("email"), "email is required"
     password = cred.pop('password')
     user = get_user_model().objects.filter(**cred).last()
     if user.check_passowrd(password):
          return user
</code>

Comment: the problem was that password was on read-only = True, so it wasn't actually getting the password

Answer (score 0):

There is not problem with this code, The problem is with the creation of users, I can't get to set the password properly.